# Get selected image in imagePickerController and pass it to coreML

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, coreml

I'm trying to do the recognition by using coreML, the function working and showing the result correctly. But I want to call the method into a button, like when I pressed the catDog button and it runs the method. But since the finalResult() and identifyCatOrDog() is its own function, so that I can't call it into the button. I tried to copy and paste the method inside the button, but it doesn't show me anything. How can I edit the code so that findResult() only work when I pressed the button not running automatically?

```
import UIKit
import CoreML
import Vision
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var loadImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var Result: UILabel!

@IBAction func photoBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    getPhoto()
}

@IBAction func cameraBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func catDog(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getPhoto() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let gotImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("No picture chosen")
    }

    loadImage.image = gotImage
    identifyCatOrDog(image: gotImage)
}

func identifyCatOrDog(image: UIImage) {
    let modelFile = ImageClassifier()
    let model = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: modelFile.model)

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image.cgImage!, options: [ : ])

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: findResults)
    try! handler.perform([request])
}

func findResults(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
        fatalError("Unable to get results")
    }

    var bestGuess = ""
    var bestConfidence: VNConfidence = 0

    for classification in results {
        if (classification.confidence > bestConfidence) {
            bestConfidence = classification.confidence
            bestGuess = classification.identifier
        }
    }

    Result.text = "Image is: \(bestGuess) with confidence \(bestConfidence) out of 1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the problem is that sometimes when the image picker is dismissed, you want to call `identifyCatOrDog`, but other times you don’t.

One rather crude possibility is this: In the button action method, raise a bool instance property flag so that when `didFinishPickingMedia` is called you know whether or not to call `identifyCatOrDog`.

A more sophisticated way would be to divide things off into helper classes so that the operation of the image picker after pressing the `catDog` button takes place within a completely different code world.

Comment: I tried to use UIswitch to solve this problem, I add those link of code: if (catDogSwitch.isOn) {
            identifyCatOrDog(image: gotImage)
        } else if (faceSwitch.isOn){
            identifyFacesWithLandmarks(image: gotImage)
        }